# PHP preg_match_all string begins with @ following by any character

Tags: preg-match-all

I have this line of code:

```
preg_match_all('/(?!\b)(@\w+\b)/', $s, $rgMatches);
```

$s is a long string (including spaces) to be searched, $rgMatches is an array of matches

That line of code will match with strings such as @blahblah or @blah22blah
However, if the string contains @blah.blah (a dot among letters) it does not match.

How can I improve my code?

Comment: Why do you write `(?!\b)` at the begining?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it just for sure, but it can be removed, no problem, the second part needs to be fixed

Comment: Sure of what? What are you trying to do? are you trying do find users but not emails?

Comment: In members' comments, I want to bold the username which begins with an '@' (e.g @TransientWind). Unfortunately, usernames which has '.' among letters does not work with my patern (e.g @Transient.Wind)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
/\B@\w+(?:\.\w+)*/
```

or more permissive:

```
/\B@[\w.]+/
```

The `\B` may not be useful with what you want to do, it is a translation of `(?!\b)`

Comment: how about this examples @Transient@Wind or @Transient#Wind

Comment: @TransientWind: It is not what you asked in your original question.

Comment: sorry I should mention about special characters, I just remembered one case which was a dot...